# How to detect GMaps drawing manager polygon edit?

Tags: drawing, polygon, edit, detect

How can I detect the event of polygon edit? When I draw it I have the event `polygon complete` but when I edit its edges..? I tried with `drawingmode_changed` but it's not working.

[image]

Comment: What code have you tried to detect the event? Where you do thing you need to start?

Comment: I have the code to build and store polygons in the database but i don't know where to detect the changes to the created polygons.